# except operation on two dataframe having a map column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes dfA and dfB. I want to remove all occurrences of dfB from dfA. The problem however is that they have a column which is of datatype map. except operation doesn't work well with that.

```
+--------+----------------------------------
|id  | fee_amount   | optional             | 
|1   | 10.00        | { 1 -> abc, 2-> def  |
|2   | 20.0         | { 3 -> pqr, 5-> stu  |
```

I was thinking I could drop the column somehow and add it back but it won't work because I wouldn't know which rows got removed from dfA. Options?

Comment: if you want to remove the content of map, then you can explode on map column from both the datframe and perform except.

Comment: use a leftanti join

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work well", does it work or not? Is it too slow?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth sorry I meant It doesn't work. I'll look at leftanti join.